# Error no 104 is displayed when trying to download pihole

Tags: pi-hole

I am trying to add pihole to my network but when I type the curl -sSL command, it gives some checks and then says this -
[image]

so basically, I don't understand what am I meant to do here?

EDIT: Sorry guys, i had to download it as root, so did some stuff but Thank you for the help anyways...

Now its working
YAY
[image]

Comment: what do you see when you read that message?

Comment: You need to prepend sudo to the command you are typing.

Comment: There is missing information.